# Update primary key

Tags: primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have a table  as A (code,id,num,address)

Here code, id, and num are primary keys and no Foreign key dependency is present on any other table.

I need to update `num` using `id`… can I do that?

num was telephone number.i figurd this out.but i have another question

can we update the same column  num using num only.example
UPDATE A
SET num = ''
WHERE num = '';

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific? What exactly do you mean by "update `num` using `id`"?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `update num using id`? And do I understand correctly that `num` and `id` are 2 different primary keys, rather than only the pair `<num, id>` is a primary key?

Comment: @Miky: LOL - we asked the same thing with exactly the same wording :)))

Comment: @Armen: Ha ha.. yeah, that should hint at something!

Comment: can we update the same column  num using num only.example
UPDATE A
SET num = '<newvalue>'
WHERE num = '<oldvalue>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE A
SET num = '<value>'
WHERE id = '<identifier>';
```

Should suffice, if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
update A
set num = $someValue
where id = $someOtherValue;
```

You say there are no foreign keys that rely on this key so why not?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the primary key will still be unique after the update and given that you did not define something like "alway generated" for this column: Yes, you can.